Looking for a Monster/Werewolf movie that ends with two characters in the woods with a yellow tent
One of the characters is in the tent surrounded by weapons, the other is sitting outside on guard. As they are chatting, suddenly the guy outside disappears. The man in the tent picks up a bazooka, and when the monster bursts into the tent, he blows them both up. I saw it sometime in the 90s, but don't remember exactly when.

It was on TV (don't know if it was a show or movie) in the 90s. I can't remember exactly when. Maybe the late 90s?

Do you recall what the monsters looked like? Like, were they furry like werewolves? And were they people who transformed into monsters?

This is Howling 3: The Marsupials.
The tent scene is at the end of Act 2, rather than the end of the film, but it basically plays out as you've described; Two soldiers in a yellow tent. One gets taken and the other uses a bazooka from inside the tent to blow up the monster.




YES! That is it. Awesome. I did not know there was more!

@Siriss - Happy to help
